# Ajax response getting php tag as prefix in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am working on an issue which is in existing project.The project is build in laravel (version 5.8).The issue is that when any web pages is loaded of web application then first line of code will be commented.And there is one more issue is that when any form is submitted through ajax then in response always i got "`<?` (PHP tag)" as prefix.So i am not identifying how it is coming.

I have tried one solution that removing the PHP tag from the empty routes file but still issue is not been fixed.Below is the link of it from where i got the way of solving the issue but it is not working :

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21581

Below is the image of the commented code and the response of ajax which i am getting all the time.

1) First line of code will be commented all the time when any of the page is loaded.

[image]

2) When any of the ajax call of the application then in response i got "`<?` (PHP tag)" as prefix.

[image]

Please provide me solution as soon as possible because i am trying to resolve the issue since a week but still issue is not fixed.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please paste your controller and blade code so that we can help you in better way

Comment: @KhalidKhan Sorry but i can't disclose the code.But one thing to say is that when i call routes and in that if i print some text instead of calling method then text will also display in comments rather than print in the web page.Below code is for demo purpose :

 Route::get('/testing', function(){ 
            echo 'Testing'; 
                   });

Comment: Bro no one is going to steal your code here, because without code it's always hard to figure out what is wrong. but still if your code is confidential then don't share :)

Comment: I know that try to understand it is confidential that's why i am not sharing.But i have also mention a link of "github" in the question you can visit that.My issue is similar with that.

Comment: Actually <? is not abug in laravel. You might've opened <? this somewhere in your blade or route.php file

Comment: As I have check that even after print some text in route file then also it is coming and even in all ajax call in response i am facing same thing.And in routes file there is php tag opened and close there is no extraa "<?" tag is there.

Comment: Does non-Laravel PHP work?  Eg if you just put a `foo.php` in your `public/` dir, does it work or is the same problem there?  If it also shows the problem, it is some PHP/webserver config thing.  If not, it is in Laravel, trace through code from `index.php` forward, try to find out where that is happening.  I assume you've checked your layouts?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have checked by creating file in public folder and in that there is no such type of issue occur.And i am trying to trace the code in laravel.File which i am tracing in laravel is 1) index.php 2) bootstrap/app.php 3) config/app.php.
In all this file text which i have print is not commented working fine but when i print text in routes.php at begining then text will be commented.